# Enable layout builder on custom controller page

Tags: 9, layout-builder

I created a simple page in a controller class:

```
  public function taxonomyPage($term) {
    return [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $this->t('<p>Need to render layout builder here.</p>'),
    ];
  }
```

Routing:

```
knmt_taxonomy.detail:
  path: '/tags/{term}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\knmt_taxonomy\Controller\TaxonomyController::taxonomyPage'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'edit own content'
```

For node pages i already use layout builder to render blocks, this is working fine.

I also want to use layout builder within this page. I have zero display options for now, is there a way i can enable layout builder specific for this page so i can render blocks this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to enable the layout builder without an entity which is supporting view modes.

However, it seems like you have such an entity already. So you could add a view mode at *admin/structure/display-modes/view/add/taxonomy_term*. Then visit *admin/structure/taxonomy*, select **Manage Display** of a vocabulary and enable the view mode in **Custom display settings** at the bottom of the page. Save and select the tab of the new view mode at the top. Check *Use Layout Builder* in **Layout options**, save again and click the button "Manage Layout".

In the controller render the term with the new view mode:

```
  public function taxonomyPage($term) {
    // load the term or enhance the route to load the term automatically
    // See www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes/using-parameters-in-routes
    return $this->entityTypeManager()
      ->getViewBuilder('taxonomy_term')
      ->view($term, 'my_view_mode');
  }
```